# Oracle - Grouping Sets and Pipelined Table Functions (expected NUMBER got ROW)

Tags: oracle, table-functions, grouping-sets

I'm working on a report with summary logic using `GROUPING SETS`, but I'm getting this error:

```sql
SELECT c1, c2, c3, SUM(c4) AS MySum
FROM TABLE(get_data()) src
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((c1, c2, c3), (c1, c2), c1, c2, ());

-------------------------
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got XXX.MYROW
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

It works fine when I only include `c1` or `c2` separately:

```sql
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((c1, c2, c3), (c1, c2), c1, ());  
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((c1, c2, c3), (c1, c2), c2, ());
```

It also works fine when I source the query directly from the `t1` table:

```sql
SELECT c1, c2, c3, SUM(c4) AS MySum
FROM t1 src
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((c1, c2, c3), (c1, c2), c1, c2, ());
```

What am I missing?  I feel like it's something simple.  Here's a simplified example of my setup:

```sql
-- Base table
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 VARCHAR(10), c2 VARCHAR(10), c3 VARCHAR(10), c4 INTEGER);

-- Row type
CREATE TYPE myrow AS OBJECT (c1 VARCHAR(10), c2 VARCHAR(10), c3 VARCHAR(10), c4 INTEGER);

-- Table type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mytable AS TABLE OF myrow;

-- Get data function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_mydata
RETURN mytable PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (
    SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
    FROM t1
  ) LOOP
    PIPE ROW (myrow(v_Rec.c1, v_Rec.c2, v_Rec.c3, v_Rec.c4));
  END LOOP;
    
  RETURN;    
END;
```

DB version - 12.1.0

**Update**
Different error I get with my actual function (even with "materialize" hint):

```
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item 22905. 
00000  -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" 
*Cause: attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known 
at parse time or that is not of a nested table type 
*Action: use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type
```

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9a8b820d9494a881d4e873758995519)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it won't work, but - see if this workaround helps (use a CTE and the `materialize` hint):

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select /*+ materialize */
  3      c1, c2, c3, c4
  4     from table(get_mydata()) src
  5    )
  6  select c1, c2, c3, sum(c4) as mysum
  7  from test
  8  group by grouping sets ((c1, c2, c3), (c1, c2), c1, c2, ());

C1         C2         C3              MYSUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1          2          3                   4
1                                         4
           2                              4
                                          4
1          2                              4

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great for the example I gave.  I tried applying it to my actual function, though, and I get this error :`ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" *Cause: attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at parse time or that is not of a nested table type *Action: use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type`.  This is actually the error I initially had, but which didn't show up in my simplified setup.  Same use case.  I'll keep fiddling around.

Comment: You're welcome; too bad it doesn't work in all cases ... Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround the bug by using a non-pipelined function and `BULK COLLECT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_mydata2
RETURN mytable AS
  v_data mytable;
BEGIN
  SELECT myrow(c1, c2, c3, c4)
  BULK COLLECT
  INTO v_data
  FROM t1;

  RETURN v_data;    
END;
/
```

I was able to reproduce your error in version 19c so it looks like you found a relatively big Oracle bug. In my experience, pipelined functions are generally buggier than regular functions and tend to be over-used. Pipelined functions can return data faster, but since your query is aggregating all the rows, you won't see that performance boost anyway.

The main problem with the non-pipelined function approach is that your session will need enough memory to store all of the results from the `BULK COLLECT` at once. That may not be feasible if you have to process millions of wide rows.